# MCS-51 addressing memory with DPTR needs ACC

Tags: 8051

So as I have learnt the DPTR is used to store all of the 64k addresses of ROM space and RAM (according to our demand) so that we can use register indirect addressing through this 16 bit DPTR.

Suppose I want to move a chunk of data from ROM space address 3F0H to the accumulator. So if I follow the pattern of register indirect addressing, the code should be:

```
MOV DPTR,#3F0H
MOVC A, @DPTR
```

but in reality , we do like this :

```
CLR A
MOV DPTR,#3F0H
MOVC A,@A+DPTR
```

What is the need for having to add the A and DPTR?

We could have simply load the target address in DPTR and use register indirect addressing format, so why is this?

Secondly, where the summing value get stored? In DPTR? Because the sum can be a value more than 8 bits, so no other register can store it.

Answer (score 2):

The 8051 has no `MOVC A, @DPTR` instruction. The only`MOVC` instructions are `MOVC A, @A+DPTR` and `MOVC A, @A+PC`. [Source](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_movc.htm)

Comment: So there's no logical reason behind it? It's just by definition of the coding?

Comment: @Sayan the logical reason is probably that they were running out of codes for instructions. [Look here](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_opcodes.htm) - except for one reserved opcode, all of them are used. Which instruction to you want to delete so you can use that code for `MOVC A, @DPTR` instead? Or maybe it is best to delete `MOVC A, @DPTR`?

Comment: @Sayan, that's correct, there is no apparent reason and your question is a very sensible one. You are absolutely right that it would have been very valuable to have a MOVC A,@DPTR instruction. We can only assume that design limitations prevented Intel from being able to implement it. One would hope it was not just an oversight.

Comment: @TonyM Thanks for your insight, this is what I expected.

Comment: (Alternatively, perhaps some instructions should become two bytes; but perhaps the 8051 designers wanted all instructions to be one byte to make the circuitry simpler)